# MySQL Easily Join Several Tables

Tags: mysql

All,
  I have several tables, over 50, who have a common column "MYID" and can't figure out an easier way to join them without writing a gigantic query.

Imagine the following sample (only with 50 tables and 50 data points)

```
SELECT DATAPOINT1, DATAPOINT2, DATAPOINT3, DATAPOINT4, DATAPONT5
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3, TABLE4, TABLE5
WHERE TABLE1.MYID = TABLE2.MYID, MYTABLE2.MYID=MYTABLE3.MYID, MYTABLE4.MYID=MYTABLE5.MYID
```

How would I achieve the above results with a shorter query?

Comment: Well you title uses the word JOIN. Why not start by using the MYSQL JOIN Syntax

Comment: 50 tables? Sounds like a database design error was made earlier on in the design process

Comment: Design error it might be, and I can redo the entire schema but I've always wondered this so I'm interested in the answer anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a horrible database design. The query you are showing is about what you need. Many, many tables to join, but that's the way it is with the design given. It cannot be shorter, because you need to list all the columns, all the tables and all criteria. There is nothing you can remove.

With proper join syntax:

```
select 
  t1.datapoint1, 
  t2.datapoint2, 
  t3.datapoint3,
  ...
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.myid = t1.myid
join table3 t3 on t3.myid = t1.myid
join ...
```

Very easy to generate with a programming language loop or Excel for instance.

Comment: Thank you.  By the way.  I changed the schema to be in a single table, but wanted to ask the question while it was fresh in my head.